How to achieve this overlapping effect in Jetpack compose
How do I achieve this overlapping effect in Jetpack compose. I am trying to get the precise position and placement just like the one shown in the picture, specifically of the ones circled in blue, the close X button and the way the picture preview is placed ontop of the textfield. Using Box with Alignment.CenterStart for the image ontop of the textfield and Alignment.TopStart for the Image with x button at the topleft does not achieve the desired effect. Any help whatsoever would be appreciated
Picture below :

Okay so below is the attached code, and what I have been trying plus the issue that I am currently facing.
@Composable
fun MessageTextField(
    value: String,
    placeholder: Clause,
    imageUri: List<Uri>?,
    onCaptureImageClick: () -> Unit,
    onPickImageClick: () -> Unit,
    onSendButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    onRemoveImageClick: (Uri) -> Unit,
    onValueChange: (value: String) -> Unit
) {

    val containerShape = RoundedCornerShape(
        topStart = 20.dp,
        topEnd = 20.dp
    )

    Box {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(containerShape)
                .border(
                    width = 0.2.dp,
                    color = Theme.colors.border.primaryOnLight,
                    shape = containerShape
                )
                .background(color = 
Theme.colors.surfaceInteractive.enabledOnLight)
                .padding(
                    top = Theme.spacing.x3
                )
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = value,
                onValueChange = onValueChange,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = 
KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Transparent
                ),
                textStyle = Theme.typography.textField.copy(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    fontSize = TEXT_FONT_SIZE.sp,
                ),
                placeholder = {
                    Text(clause = placeholder)
                },
                trailingIcon = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = onSendButtonClick,
                        enabled = if (value.isNotBlank()) true else 
false,
                        content = {
//                            SendButton()
                        }
                    )
                },
                maxLines = 6
            )

            Column(modifier = Modifier.height(25.dp)) {
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = value.isNotBlank(),
                    enter = scaleIn(),
                    exit = scaleOut()
                ) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 
Theme.spacing.x4)) {
                        Image(
                            image = 
Image.Drawable(R.drawable.ic_camera),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(22.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    onCaptureImageClick.invoke()
                                }
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = 
Modifier.width(Theme.spacing.x3))
                        Image(
                            image = Image.Drawable(R.drawable.ic_upload),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(22.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    onPickImageClick.invoke()
                                }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        
Spacer(Modifier.windowInsetsBottomHeight(WindowInsets.navigationBars))
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .zIndex(2f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationX = 100f
                    translationY = -200f
                }
        ) {
            imageUri?.forEach {
                DismissibleImage(
                    uri = it,
                    onRemove = { }
                )
            }

        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun DismissibleImage(uri: Uri, onRemove: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .background(color = Theme.colors.surface.primaryDark)
                .size(DISMISSABLE_IMAGE_SIZE.dp)
        )

        Icon(
            image = Icons.Navigation.close,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(Theme.spacing.x8)
                .zIndex(1f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationX = -25f
                    translationY = -25f
                },
            onClick = onRemove
        )
    }
}

Then this is the result of the code. This is the current issue hat I am facing, something is sort of covering the first half of the Box/Image after using a translationY of 200f


Please edit your post and include the minimal code that you currently have.

Okay @BenjyTec I will do that now. I am currently attempting to try to move the Box/Image with the graphicsLayer{} with translationX and translationY and it basically works partially. But I will share the code in PasteBin as it is quite big, but easy to read and understand.

@BenjyTec I have just made the edit, I am trying to move the Box with the graphicsLayer modifier but this is the issue that I am encountering.

Have you tried to use the offset Modifer?

No @BenjyTec but I will try that now

@BenjyTec the offset modifier is producing the same result.

The Problem your facing with something covering your box is likely to be because your Box hasn't enough height to show the top part of you box. You can check that by adding backgrounds to you components (Columns and Boxes) to check if the sizes are enough

I have not tried adding some backgrounds yet but it seems that after doing some research, what seems to cause this is the use of that horizontalScroll modifier attribute that I have in the row. It seems that modifier attribute clips the content of which it is applied to both on the main and cross axis.

Reference is here https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ClipScrollableContainer.kt;l=47-83?q=HorizontalScrollableClipModifier&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport

I would implement it to have the images on the same layer as the chat and the textfield to have something like a Stack.
Example:
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(100) {
            Divider()
            Text("Item $it")
            Divider()
        }
        item {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .height(80.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth())
        }
    }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .height(80.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Red)
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter))

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 40.dp, bottom = 50.dp) //crucial for overlapping look
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
    )
}


The red Box represents the Textfield and the blue Box the media you want to add. To achieve the overlapping look I decided to align the blue box to the bottom start and add padding on the start and bottom

I am following your solution but there is an issue, I have like two icons placed at the bottom of the textfield, for some reason I cannot click them when I follow this exact solution which is by placing the Blue box this way(in this case, the image) I cannot click on those two icons. Just picture two small icons that are under the blue box. I'm not sure why that is happening.

I am thinking its because of the blue box because when I remove it, it works

Are the icons aligned to the start of the red box? I tried with adding a Textbutton aligned to the CenterStart of the Red Box and I can click it.

sorry for late reply. Yes I think they are aligned
